# Telerik Winforms Theme is not applied to windows form

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, telerik

This happens ONLY when using RibbonControl!

I've created a new Radribbonform and drag and dropped the metro theme via the designer on my form. Then I've added the following code:

```
 Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    Dim theme As New Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Windows8Theme()
    ThemeResolutionService.ApplicationThemeName = "Windows8"
End Sub
```

It changes the theme but as you can see the borders are still in the standard windows look. In designer however it works but only when I run the form it looks like that:

[image]

Comment: What Op system are you using... I had similar look using Win8 theme but my Op system was Win10

Comment: Windows 8.1, this only happens when working with RibbonControl (either on radform or on a radribbonform). When using a radform only the border is in telerik style.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try apply the theme when the window is loaded and the controls are rendered, in the event-invocator `OnShown` for example? stills happenning the same?.

---

i'm not sure but maybe it could be a bug in the lib version that you are using, anyways try using the `Telerik.WinControls.ThemeResolutionService.ApplyThemeToControlTree` instead, on the **Form** on which the **Ribbon** is.

Code taken from my **[ElektroKit](https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/tree/master/Solution/v1.5/Elektro.Application.ThirdParty/Telerik)** API:

```
Public Shared Sub SetFormVisualTheme(form As Form, theme As TelerikVisualThemes)

    form.SuspendLayout()
    form.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None

    ThemeResolutionService.ApplyThemeToControlTree(form, theme.ToString)

    form.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font
    form.ResumeLayout()

End Sub

Public Enum TelerikVisualThemes As Integer
    AllThemes = 0
    Aqua = 1
    Breeze = 2
    Desert = 4
    Office2007Black = 8
    Office2007Silver = 16
    Office2010Black = 32
    Office2010Blue = 64
    Office2010Silver = 128
    Office2013Light = 256
    Office2013Dark = 512
    TelerikMetro = 1024
    TelerikMetroBlue = 2048
    TelerikMetroTouch = 4096
    VisualStudio2012Light = 8192
    VisualStudio2012Dark = 16384
    Windows7 = 32768
    Windows8 = 65536
End Enum
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `AllowAero` property of the RibbonForm to false.